# Pass variable from routes in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a page where I want to display weather. But the weather depends on timezone.
I don't want to make such route as:

```
Route::get('/weather/{timezone}', array('uses' => 'MyController@method'));
```

It's more convenient for me to do something like:

```
Route::get('/weather/Paris', array('uses' => 'MyController@method', 'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris'));
```

But I'm not sure how to do that. This is not the only case. The general issue is: when I want to pass something to controller depending on my url, but it maybe something more complex than user id or something like that

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why its more convenient for you to hardcode routes and their corresponding parameters in your routes.php

Wouldn't it be better to simply accept city names in your {timezone} parameter, and get the corresponding timezone from a look-up table?

```
Route::get('weather/{city}', array('uses' => 'MyController@method'));
```

MyController::method function definition:

```
function method ($city) {
// convert city name to timezone
$timezone = cityToTimezone($city);

// Use $timezone as you need to
}
```

**In any case, to answer your question, no. I haven't come across anything in the Laravel docs to suggest that what you need is possible.**

Comment: Well, I just didn't want to do this conversion between city and timezone. Thanks, I'll do it that way.